# CORS cookies work with get request but not with post in Angular2

Tags: javascript, http, angular, cookies, cors

I am trying to connect an angular2 app with a rails api.

In order to use rails authentication I want to be able to share cookies between two domains. When I call http GET in my angular app I get back a response with a set cookie field as expected, and when I send the next GET request the cookie is sent along. However, when I replace the second GET with a POST, it is not. I am using withCredentials = true for both calls.

When I call the following:

```
let options : RequestOptionsArgs = {};
options.withCredentials = true;
this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'sessions/login_attempt' ,options)
  .toPromise();
```

I can see the request headers in chrome dev tools that the cookies are sent along:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:request_method=GET; _commandsapp_session=SlRJdHdPQ3dadG94RDFWYmIxVWNnZnZUMzRwSU5pMjhoQ1NWV1loN2lNWUdIMTFrNmZyV2dJcWV4RHZON0p6WTJRcVRNSU8zM3BXV0dIWnJ4QXpYaEdSYUVLR1cvT3N6Wm1XNWxUVDJ6c3ltbll1dk9OSFdJdDZIdW5SM25BYTdOSGtwelhGU0NDRG1WZXQwSzlHZCt3PT0tLWwrc1BrWVA5Tk84ZEU4VE8zcUQ4L0E9PQ%3D%3D--f201c0d6e0fe67de323a10fb521614d165a50964
Host:0.0.0.0:3000
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:4200
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36
```

However when I replace it with post and add a body I can't see that chrome is sending the cookies.

```
let options : RequestOptionsArgs = {};
    options.withCredentials = true;
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'sessions/login_attempt', {'username_or_email': 'admin', 'login_password':'password'} ,options)
      .toPromise();
```

Request headers in chrome dev tools:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:0.0.0.0:3000
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:4200
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second request is a [pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), you have to respond to it with permission to make the POST request before the browser will make the POST request (which will include the cookies).